# Stretchable UIImage chat bubbles

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

I have the following image attached that I use as the background of each of my chat messages (i.e. bubbles). What values should I use for X and Y in UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: X topCapHeight: Y]; to insure that the pointy end of the image stays in the middle at all times.

I tried using X=20 Y=5 but the pointy end goes to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Are you really using iOS 4.0 or is this mis-tagged?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with a single stretchable image. A stretchable image always has just one rectangular area that is stretched. To get the appearance you want however, you'd need to stretch two parts – the areas above *and* below the pointer.

You need to use at least two images. The easiest would probably be to make the pointer a separate image and center it manually on top of the rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that and keep the arrow in the center -- well, not in iOS 6 and earlier ;-)

This is why the little speech arrow in Messages.app is at the bottom corner of the speech bubbles. They stretch an area of pixels that is just above that region.

So, you could make things easier for yourself by following Messages.app's lead and design around the limitation.